# Compiling with wildcard generics

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

I'm working on the Java OCP exam, and I came across this question

Given the following code:

```
Transaction t1 = new Transaction<>(1, 2); //1
Transaction t2 = new Transaction<>(1, "2"); //2
```

It is required that //1 must compile and //2 must NOT compile.  Which of the following declarations of class Transaction will satisfy the request?

The answer is this one:

```
public class Transaction<T, S extends T> {
   public Transaction(T t, S s) {

   }
}
```

Which I understand.  But when I put this code into an Eclipse project, it works!  Here is my code:

```
class TransactionD<T, S extends T> {
    public TransactionD(T t, S s){
        System.out.println("D: t: " + t.getClass() + " s: " + s.getClass());
    }
}
public class Test1
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TransactionD d1 = new TransactionD<>(1, 2);    //1
        TransactionD d2 = new TransactionD<>(1, "2"); //2
    }

}
```

My output is this:

D: t: class java.lang.Integer s: class java.lang.Integer

D: t: class java.lang.Integer s: class java.lang.String

My question is this: what am I missing?

Comment: What is the Java version your book or mock test is targeting? "OCP" seems Java5/6-ish.

Comment: try sending `new Integer(1), "2"` to your `TransactionD` constructor

Comment: @Mena it's 7 or 8 (I'm actually a professor working with students who are using either 7 or 8, so I'm not sure which version this student is in)

Comment: @CraigR8806 It seems that that would just negate the need for autoboxing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using raw types in your declaration, you are actually using `TransactionD<Object, Object>`, and this makes the call valid, as according to java generics, `Object` extends `Object`, and both `Integer` and `String` also extend Object.

Comment: Turning on all compiler warnings would have revealed this.